# cannot read of props null in react js

Tags: reactjs

when trying to click the delete button the error is displayed stating that cannot read props of null  and try to bind the method in the constructor class using bind.this but again the same error is displayed. also bind the value at the bottom of the component again the same error that cannot read value of props as null

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import SampleData from './data.js';
            import _ from 'lodash';
            import AppList from './Applist';
            import Appointment from './Appointment';
            import './App.css';


            class App extends Component {
            constructor(){
             super()
            this.state = {
             data:[],
             aptBodyVisible: false
            }
            this.deleteMessage = this.deleteMessage.bind(this);
            this.toggleAddDisplay = this.toggleAddDisplay.bind(this);
            }
          componentDidMount(){
            this.setState({data: SampleData})
          }
          deleteMessage(item) {
            var allApts = this.state.data;
        var newApts = _.without(allApts, item);
        this.setState({
          data: newApts
        });
          }
        toggleAddDisplay(){
          var tempVisibility = !this.state.aptBodyVisible;
          this.setState({
            aptBodyVisible: tempVisibility

          })
        }
        render() {
            var filtered = this.state.data;
            filtered = filtered.map((item, index)=>{
             return( 
               <AppList key = { index }
                 singleItem = { item }
                 whichItem = { item }
                 onDelete = {this.deleteMessage}
                  />
         )
            })
        return (
          <div className="main">
            <Appointment 
            bodyVisible = { this.state.aptBodyVisible } 
            handleToggle = { this.toggleAddDisplay } />
            <ul className="item-list media-list">{filtered} </ul>
        </div>

            );
          }
        }


        export default App;

         child class  component 
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class AppList extends Component {
       handleDelete(){
           this.props.onDelete(this.props.whichItem);
        }
        render(){
            return(
            <li className="pet-item media">
                <div className="media-left">
                    <button className="pet-delete btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                    onClick = {this.handleDelete}>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                    </div>
            <div className="pet-head">
              <span className="pet-name">{this.props.singleItem.petName}</span>
              <span className="apt-date pull-right">{this.props.singleItem.aptDate}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="owner-name"><span className="label-item">Owner:</span>
              {this.props.singleItem.ownerName}</div>
              <div className="apt-notes">{this.props.singleItem.aptNotes}</div>
    </li>
            )
        }
    }

    export default AppList;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

Like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data:[],
    aptBodyVisible: false
  }
  this.deleteMessage = this.deleteMessage.bind(this);
  this.toggleAddDisplay = this.toggleAddDisplay.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes again we need to bind the method in the child components even to work with the click events
onClick = {this.handleDelete.bind(this)}